# Store data based on location in a dataset python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Forgive me if this question is trivial, I am just having some trouble finding a solution online, and I'm a bit new to python. Essentially, I have a dataset which is full of various numbers all of which are arranged in this format:

```
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
```

I'm trying to write some python to get the number on either side of the comma. I assume it's some type of splitting, but I can't seem to find anything that works for this problem specifically since I want to take the ALL the numbers from the left and store them in a variable, then take ALL the numbers on the right store them in a variable. The goal is to plot the data points, and normally I would modify the data set, but it's a challenge problem so I am trying to figure this out with the data as is.

Comment: Please show what have you come up with so far(code), so it's easier to help.

Comment: Try something. Use `csv` module for reading. This is basic csv.

Comment: You can use the `csv` module to split each line into two element rows, then convert them to floats and append to x and y lists. Alternately, you can use `pandas` to read them into a two dimensional array. `pandas` makes it handle columns of data so plotting should be straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
with open('mydata.csv') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

left_numbers, right_numbers = [], []

for line in lines:
    numbers = line.split(',')
    left_num = float(numbers[0])
    right_num = float(numbers[1])
    left_numbers.append(left_num)
    right_numbers.append(right_num)
```

Edit: added float conversion

Comment: So by using "append" for the left_numbers and right_numbers, will they be stored as integer typed values? Or will I have to do a conversion? It looks to me by your use of square brackets that you've stored them in an array? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Good catch, added the type conversion to float. The append method just adds an item to a list.